# How to include generated sources with Gradle's javadoc task?

Tags: gradle, javadoc

In my Gradle project, sources are generated into

```
build/
    generated/
        annotationProcesor/
            java/
                main/
                test/
```

And it's just works with command line and IntelliJ.

When I tried to generate javadoc, linkes to those generated source codes are not recognized.

e.g.

```java
    // link to one of those generated source codes; static metamodel
    /**
     * A value for {@link MyEntity_#discriminator} attribute.
     */
```

How can I make `gradle javadoc` task succeeds?